Proof to Sharkovsky's Theorem of odd period case.
I'm reading Devaney's "An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems" and I cannot understand the proof to Sharkovsky's Theorem in the case of odd period. In particular, (details below) the paragraph (p.78 in 3rd edition)

Now, if $ k < n - 1 $, then one of the loops $ I_1 \to I_2 \to \ldots \to I_k \to I_1 $ or $ I_1 \to I_2 \to \ldots \to I_k \to I_1 \to I_1 $ gives a fixed point of $f^m$ with $m$ odd and $ m < n $. This point must have prime period $ < k $ since $ I_1 \cap I_2 $ consists of only one point, and that point have period $ > m $. Therefore $ k = n - 1 $.

I can understand everything except how "$ I_1 \cap I_2 $ consists of only one point, and that pint have period $ > m $" implies "This point must have prime period $ < k $". They doesn't seem to have any relation to me...
It is true that $ I_1 \cap I_2 $ consists of at most one point, say $x_j$, but since it's on the orbit of $x$, $x_j$ also has period $n$ which is greater than $m$. I don't understand how it implies that the fixed point of $f^m$ then has to have prime period $ < k $. This fixed point we have here can be in interior of $I_1$, which has nothing to to with $ I_1 \cap I_2 $.
Thanks in advance!

Full detail:
Let $f$ be a continuous function and $x$ is a point of period $n$ with $n$ odd. Let $ x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n $ be the orbit of $x$. Then $f$ simply permutes the points $x_i$'s. Since $ f(x_n) < x_n $ and $ f(x_1) > x_1 $ be construction, there is a maximal index $i$ such that $ f(x_i) > x_i $. Then necessarily, we have $ f(x_{i+1}) < x_{i+1} $. This implies that, letting $ I_1 = [ x_i, $x_{i+1} ], $ f(I_1) \supset I_1 $. We write $ I \to J $ if $ f(I) \supset J $. Using this notation we have $ I_1 \to I_1 $.
Since each $x_j$ is in the orbit of $x$, $ x_i, x_{i+1} $ cannot have period $2$ and $ f(I_1) $ must contain other interval of the form $ [ x_j, x_{j+1} ] $ form some $j$. We define $ \mathcal{O}_2 $ be the union of intervals of the form $ [ x_j, x_{j+1} ] $ that is covered by $ f(I_1) $. Therefore, for any $ I_2 \subset \mathcal{O}_2 $, we have $ I_1 \to I_2 $.
We continue this construction recursively. $ \mathcal{O}_{l+1} $ is the collection of the intervals of the form $ [ x_j, x_{j+1} ] $ that are covered by image of one of the interval of the form $ [ x_j, x_{j+1} ] $ contained in $ \mathcal{O}_l $. Then by construction, for any interval $I_l$ in $\mathcal{O}_l$, there exists a chain of intervals such that $ I_1 \to I_2 \to \ldots \to I_l $.
Since $\{x_j\}$ is the orbit of $x$ and $x$ has prime period $n$, $\mathcal{O}_l$ forms an increasing nested sequence which will terminate/stabilize after finite steps, i.e., $ \mathcal{O}_l = \mathcal{O}_{l+1} = [ x_1, x_n ] $ for some $l$.
Using the fact that $n$ is odd, it is not hard to see there is an interval $I$ in some $\mathcal{O}_k$ such that $ I \to I_1 $ since there is at least one pair of points $ x_j, x_{j+1} $ that will have image lying on different sides of $I_1$. This allow us to find loops of the form $ I_1 \to I_2 \to \ldots \to I_k \to I_1 $, where each interval is of the form $ [ x_j, x_{j+1} ] $. We let $k$ be the least integer that this happens with additional condition that $ I_1 \ne I_2 $.
Now, if $ k < n - 1 $, then one of the loops $ I_1 \to I_2 \to \ldots \to I_k \to I_1 $ or $ I_1 \to I_2 \to \ldots \to I_k \to I_1 \to I_1 $ gives a fixed point of $f^m$ with $m$ odd and $ m < n $. This point must have prime period $ < k $ since $ I_1 \cap I_2 $ consists of only one point, and that point have period $ > m $. Therefore $ k = n - 1 $.
...
the proof goes on, but it's almost done. This is the only spot that I'm stuck with this proof. If you need any more details, please let me know!
